# Glue Crawler unable to exclude .csv.metadata files

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have an S3 location `s3://bucket-name/folder-name/` which consists of a subfolder whose name is dynamically generated which contains the phrase `_Top10InvoiceIds`. This subfolder consists of `.csv` and `.csv.metadata` files. I am using a glue crawler to crawl only the csv files and view them in Athena. But I am unable to exclude the `.csv.metadata` files. I have tried all the possible regular expression patterns as the glob value.

Some of my attempts have been:

1. `*_Top10InvoiceIds/ *.metadata`
2. `*_Top10InvoiceIds/ * .* metadata`
3. `*_Top10InvoiceIds/ *. *.metadata`
4. `*_Top10InvoiceIds/ * .csv.metadata`
5. `** .metadata`
6. `* .metadata`
7. `* .csv.metadata`
8. `* /*.metadata`

It would be great if someone could help me figure out the pattern or suggest another way of doing the same.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you were trying to prevent the .metadata files from showing up as data in your Athena table by using exclusions in Glue Crawlers.

Glue Crawlers are for creating table definitions and associated metadata for said tables. In terms of populating data into tables, that's Athena:

> Crawler
>
> A program that connects to a data store (source or target), progresses through
> a prioritized list of classifiers to **determine the schema for your data**,
> and then creates metadata tables in the AWS Glue Data Catalog.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/components-key-concepts.html

Tables made in Athena grab all of the data underneath the bucket path you list in the include pattern:

> **Important**
>
> Athena reads all data stored under the 's3://bucketname/prefix/'. If you have
> data that you do not want Athena to read, do not store that data in the same
> Amazon S3 prefix as the data you want Athena to read. If you are leveraging
> partitioning, to ensure Athena scans data within a partition, your WHERE filter
> must include the partition. For more information, see Table Location and
> Partitions.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-location-format.html

I think if you want to exclude the data from your table, it will need its own subfolder

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple answer for you:

Athena **will not** honour Glue exclude patterns. These patterns are only to exclude un necessary files that you don't want to scan while crawling and to use in Glue ETL.So if you want to exclude these .metadata files then you need to write an automated script to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `**/*.csv.metadata` or `**/*.metadata` exclusion pattern